# How can I create an Adobe Acrobat action that prints a PDF as a PDF without any user prompt?

Tags: pdf, script, printing, adobe-acrobat

How can I create a Adobe Acrobat action that prints a PDF as a PDF without any user prompt?

I tried:

[image]

Info when clicking on "specify settings":

[image]

Info when hitting  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> :

[image]

but when running the action on one PDF file there is a user prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Printers in Control panel
2. Right-click on "Adobe PDF " printer and go to "Printing preferences"
3. Go to the "Adobe PDF Output folder" option and select any folder you want